# Wordpress Custom Endpoint shows 404

Tags: wordpress, rest

I am stuck on creating custom endpoints. I followed this tutorial to create custom endpoints. But, it always returns 404.
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

I added code below to function.php:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('awesome/v1', '/awesomeparams', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_awesome_params',
    'args' => array(),
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return true;
    }
  ));
});
function get_awesome_params( $data ) {
    return "aaaa";
}
```

When I trying to access: http://www.my-domain.com/wp-json/awesome/v1/awesomeparams

It shows 404:
[image: 404 error]

I also tried to flush the permalinks by going to WordPress admin -> Settings -> Permalinks and click save.

Can I get some help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I could not get response from ```http://smap.cas.mcmaster.ca```
and I suggest using https, for some reason I remeber that reast-api is meant only for https

Comment: @Mulli Thanks for trying. That url is not public available yet. It shoube in vpn.

Comment: Try using ```https://www.postman.com/``` and verify step by step that your rest api is dunctioning as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the url below:
http://www.my-domain.com/index.php/wp-json/awesome/v1/awesomeparams